# SQL Query not getting values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying get the values using SP.The query is below.

```
 create proc [dbo].[GetOrdersByUserID11]    
(    
@UserID int    
)    
as    
begin    
declare @status varchar(1000)

set @status=' select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('''' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations  a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID '   
set @status=@status+' Join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = '+convert(varchar(10),@UserID)+''

 set @status=@status+'Order By CategoryText, CourseTitle '   

print @status

exec(@status)

 select * from #myCourses1

end

This is message from my query when run my SP[[dbo].[GetOrdersByUserID11] 5085  ]:


 select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations  a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID  Join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = 5085

(99 row(s) affected)
```

i am getting message 99 rows affected but in my results getting only header with 0(zero) columns.

Plz do help me for getting values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temp table you create is only within scope of the EXEC statements, not the outer query.

```
exec('select 1 as f into #t') 
select * from #t'  <-- out of scope
```

Select within the statement:

```
exec('select 1 as f into #t; select * from #t')
```

Or create the temp table first (so create/select are within the same scope).

```
select 1 as f into #t where 0=1 --force empty
exec('insert #t values (2)') 
select * from #t
```

Comment: +1 for clarifying the base principal of scopes in queries. It is sometimes more tricky than it first seems

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you first put your query in a string variable. Does the query below do what you need ?

```
create proc [dbo].[GetOrdersByUserID11]    
(    
    @UserID int    
)    
AS    
BEGIN

SELECT a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast("" as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, 
    PurchasedDate as dateadded
FROM dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations a 
    JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID
    JOIN Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = convert(varchar(10),@UserID)
ORDER By CategoryText, CourseTitle

END
```

Call stored procedure:

`EXEC GetOrdersByUserID11(1234);`

Comment: Thank you for reply.In my query i need to add some condition for this string .If this is executed i will add later

Comment: Yes, please post the condition. I'm curious if we could add that condition without having to put the query in a string variable. Try to avoid that as much as possible :)

Comment: lol @daemon_x: yeah i saw that :D. However it may be used later, or have a purpose in the front-end

Comment: @Uw Concept - 100% sure it will; congrats to your 1st thousand anyway :)

Comment: hahaha @daemon_x, thanks! I was laughing hysterically when I saw my points total just now. *blushes*

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement is selecting the data into a temporary table instead of your result set which is being returned. If you add the following to the end of your procedure you should get your data:

```
select * from #myCourses1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you build the select request in the store procedure? As I understand your request you only want the result. In this case your better use a view with parameters in the call.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GetOrdersByUserID11]
AS
SELECT a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID 

GO
```

And you call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM GetOrdersByUserID11 Join Tbl_Orders c WHERE c.UserID = 5085
```