# SP executing error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing below SP.But when i try to run this query i am getting this error:

> There is already an object named
>   '#myCourses1' in the database.

So this getting in two else loops.  also

```
create proc [dbo].[GetOrdersByUserIDwithSubscription]     
(    
    @UserID int    
)    
as    
begin    

    declare @status varchar(500)

    declare @substatus char(2)

    select @substatus=Subscribe_status from tbl_user where userid=@userid

    print @substatus

    if  @substatus='N'

    BEGIN    
        select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations  a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID    
        Join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = @UserID and c.CourseID = a.CourseID  and c.courseprice<>'subscriber'  
        Order By CategoryText, CourseTitle         
    END  

    else if @substatus=''

    BEGIN    
        select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations  a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID    
        Join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = @UserID and c.CourseID = a.CourseID and c.courseprice<>'subscriber'   
        Order By CategoryText, CourseTitle       
    END  

    else if @substatus='Y'    
    BEGIN    
        select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded into #myCourses1 from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations  a JOIN Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID    
        Join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = @UserID and c.CourseID = a.CourseID    
        Order By CategoryText, CourseTitle 
    END
```

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018284/sql-query-not-getting-values

Comment: If you don't need the `#myCourses1` try ending the SP with a drop table: `drop table #myCourses1`. If you do need this table after the SP finished running, change the `Select .... into #myCourses1` to `Insert into #myCourses...` The problem is, i think, that this SP can be run only once, after that you have to drop #myCourses1 or use `Insert into #myCourses1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly create the temp table at the beginning of the proc.

```
CREATE TABLE #myCourses1 (
    ...
)
```

Then write your `SELECT` statements as:

```
INSERT INTO #myCourses1
    select a.*, b.CategoryText, Cast('' as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, PurchasedDate as dateadded 
        from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, the monstrocity of a query you have could be reduced to this:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetOrdersByUserIDwithSubscription](    
    @UserID int    
)    
as    
begin
    declare @substatus char(2)

    select @substatus = Subscribe_status 
    from tbl_user 
    where userid = @userid

    select a.*, b.CategoryText, 
        Cast("" as Varchar(10)) as SectionsViewed, 
        PurchasedDate as dateadded 
    from dbo.Tbl_CourseInformations a 
        join Tbl_Categories b ON a.AssignCategory = b.CategoryID
        join Tbl_Orders c ON c.UserID = @UserID 
            and c.CourseID = a.CourseID 
            and (@substatus = 'N' or c.courseprice <> 'subscriber')
    order by CategoryText, CourseTitle         

END
```

Comment: It's always nice to know who downvoted, and for whatever reason.

Comment: sorry man, it was me. I don't know how it could happen, I see no reason. I took back my downvote.

Comment: Lol! 5 years later.. xD

Comment: better late than never)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Parser is choking because you have used the same temp table name in different parts of the `IF` statement. The `IF` does not have scope like other programming languages.

If you do not need to reference the temp table outside of each of the `IF` blocks you can get around the problem by using a different table name in each part.

Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245444/there-is-already-an-object-named-columntable-in-the-database/4245552#4245552).

Answer (score 0):

You syntax is

```
SELECT [Column-List] INTO #TempTable FROM [Rest-of-Query]
```

When using this syntax, Sql Server attempts to create #TempTable on the fly based on your column list ([source](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18583)).

To get around this, either `Drop #TempTable` at the beginning of the stored procedure (if you do not need its data beyond the scope of the SP), or make it a permanent table.